# What is the compatible gcc version for cassandra c++ driver

Tags: cql

I installed Cassandra c++ driver from http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/

I am trying to compile the sample program given in http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/

I am getting the below errors:

```
g++  -lcassandra -lgcc_s basic.c -o basic
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../libcassandra.so: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4'
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../libcassandra.so: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_sub_8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../libcassandra.so: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../libcassandra.so: undefined reference to `__sync_lock_test_and_set_8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../libcassandra.so: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_8'
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../libcassandra.so: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_sub_4'
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../libcassandra.so: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can any one help me in resolving these errors.
I googled the errors and the simple solution I can find is to upgrade gcc version.
Any suggestions will really help.
Thanks in advance

Best Regards
Narayana Vasa

Comment: Can you include here your OS and gcc versions you're using? The [C++ driver docs](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/) mention the requirement is GCC 4.1.2+. You can also try the [C++ driver mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/cpp-driver-user).

Comment: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50) is the present version which I am using in my application